# How to use $ in Visual Studio Code snippets?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm working on some PHP stuff but because I don't want to write the entire defafault PHP/HTML stuff so I was making a snippet in VSCode. But then when I needed to use a `$_POST[]` in the snippet it wouldn't work because that it will use it as tabstop.

I've been trying to fix this I read somewhere that I needed to put a `\` in front of the `$` but that makes the `$` not appear at all.

Here is my snippet:

```php
"phpquickboilerplate": {
        "prefix": "phpq",
        "body": [
          "\t\t\t$4: <input type=\"${5|button,checkbox,color,date,datetime-local,email,file,hidden,image,month,number,password,radio,range,reset,search,submit,tel,text,time,url,week|}\" name=\"${6:name1}\" value=\"<?php if (empty($_POST[\"${6:name1}\"])) {echo \"$7\";} else {echo $_POST[\"${6:name1}\"];} ?>\" />",
        ],
        "description": "phpquickboilerplate"
      }
```

How can I use the `$` without making a tabstop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're right](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) that `\` can be used to escape `$`, but the `\` itself must also be escaped since it's in a JSON string, so you end up with

```
\\$_POST
```

Visual Studio Code should show an error when you just use `\$_POST`. On my machine, I see `\$` in red and the whole string gets underlined, but when I use `\\$` the `\\` goes yellow and the underlining goes away.